# How to filter results based on session variable php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, session

This has been giving me issues for quite some time.  Any help would be most appreciated!

I have a php page that is responsible for displaying information I request from a database.  I have a few buttons on the page that dictate what results will be displayed at what time.  I have a forward arrow that gets the next record, I have a back arrow that gets the previous records and then I have a filter button that I am attempting to filter my results by.

**Main PHP page**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">var mysess = <?php echo $_SESSION['verticalsess'] ?>;</script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/getresults_ab_drastic_display.js">       </script>
 <?php include("/connect.php"); ?>
 </head>

<body>
 //content
</body>
</html>
```

**//getresults_ab_display.js** 
You'll notice this JS calls another PHP file which returns the results to the original PHP file.  One function is forward results, one function is for previous results and the other is a to set a filter based on a drop down menu on the main php page.

```
$number = 1;
$(function(){
  $('#showMore').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();


    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/getNext.php",
       data: {"count":$number, vertical: mysess},

       success: function(results){
         $('#results').html(results);
         $number++;
       }
     });

  });

});

$(function(){
  $('#showLess').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/getNext.php",
       data: {"count":$number, vertical: mysess},
       success: function(results){
         $('#results').html(results);
         $number--;
       }
     });

  });

});

$(function(){
  $('#Filter').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/getNext.php",
       data: {vertical: $('#vertical').val(), pagetype: $('#pagetype').val(), primarykpitype: $('#primarykpitype').val(), count:$number},
       success: function(results){
         $('#results').html(results);
       }
     });

  });

});
```

**//getnext.php** 
This getnext looks for information passed from the js file and sends the appropriate results back.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['verticalsess'] = $_POST['vertical'];

$pstcnt = $_POST['count'];


 if ((isset($_POST['count'])) && $_SESSION['verticalsess'] = "null")
 {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM experiments LIMIT $pstcnt,1";
  }
  else{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM experiments WHERE vertical = '" . $_SESSION['verticalsess'] . "' LIMIT $pstcnt,1"; 
  }

 //my output
 ...
```

**my problem**

When I click on filter button it should send 'vertical' to my getnext php file and a) set the session variable to that value and b) return results that contain related to that vertical, HOWEVER the first time the filter button is clicked, it will pass the value for vertical and set the session variable equal to that value, however when I go to click on the get next record button, the value of the session is null...always.  So for some odd reason after the session is set the first time and the results are displayed to the screen, when I want to show the next record, mysess is set to null.

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

in //getnext.php

> $_SESSION['verticalsess'] **=** "null" ??

I think it should be

> $_SESSION['verticalsess'] **==** "null"

try that and see hwo it goes

Comment: no, that did not help, but thanks anyway.  I think it has something to do with my #showmore or #showless functions.  Like i said, the first time I use the filter the vertical is set, but when I click the showmore button and the next results are sent back to the page, the mysess var is set to null instead of retaining the value of the vertical...

Comment: when you set filter and send it to getnext.php, you should also set mysess to filter value as well.

Comment: mysess should be set to the session variable ($_SESSION['verticalsess']) and the session variable is set to 'vertical' on the click of my filter button.  Again, the problem seems to be when I click on the showmore button and getnext.php returns the results, the session variable is not always being returned...

Comment: since you are using AJAX, so you are not refreshing the page, when PHP parse your main PHP page, the mysess is set, and not changing when $_SESSION is changing.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have a giant security loophole in your SQL. You're not sanitizing anything you're passing to your database. Escape your data or use prepared statements.

Second, it's a bad idea to use `$` in Javascript, especially with jQuery loaded. So change `$number` to `number` for readability.

Third... what is the initial value of `mysess`? If I visit this page for the first time you're setting it equal to a session variable that doesn't seem to be defined. I'd at least expect to see something like

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['verticalsess'])) $_SESSION['verticalsess'] = 'somevalue';
```

Comment: appreciate the things to consider, I will look into them.  As for the mysess, it is initially set to null.  The process is, the page loads, the value is null, then I use a drop down and click on the filter button.  That passes 'vertical' to my php page and assigns that value to $_SESSION['verticalsess'].  My problem specifically is that after I use the filter, $_SESSION['verticalsess'] should essentially update itself to store the value of 'vertical'  but that is not happening...